# Storing multidimensional arrays with Morphia

Tags: unmarshalling, morphia

I have troubles reading/unmarshalling multidimensional arrays with Morphia.

The following class:

```
@Entity
class A {

  double[][] matrix;
}
```

is properly marshalled and stored in mongodb, but when reading it I get an exception that the double[][] can not be constructed. I've tried to use a custom TypeConverter but it is not getting invoked for such types.
Similar issues I get when using a member like this:

```
List<double[]> matrix;
```

I did not find any annotations that could help morphia figure out what type is expected in the array.
I suspect this is not supported yet.
Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I end up migrating to Spring-data-mongodb which allowed me to customize list marshalling.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used multi-dimensional arrays with Morphia yet, so I can't say much about that.
However, I've done the following for unsupported data types (like BigDecimal):

- Define the unsupported data type as transient
- Define a supported data type for storing your information
- Serialize / unserialize it into a supported data type via @PrePersist and @PostLoad

My code looks something like this:

```
@Transient
private BigDecimal salary;
private String salaryString;

@PrePersist
public void prePersist(){
  if(salary != null){
    this.salary = this.salary.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    salaryString = this.salary.toString();
  }
}

@PostLoad
public void postLoad(){
  if(salary != null){
    this.salary = this.salary.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    this.salary = new BigDecimal(salaryString);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is a workaround but Not what I am looking for. The extra processing required is not efficient for large collections.